# TWebBrowser and NTLM-authencation

Tags: sharepoint, delphi, iis, ntlm, twebbrowser

How can I connect with the TWebBrowser-component in Delphi from outside an ADS-Domain to a Sharepoint-Server? I've created an user-account in my domain and will connect with this information to the server.

The following code doesn't work:

```
const
USERNAME = 'JamesBond@domain.tld';
PASSWORD = 'Password2009';
var
Url, Headers: OleVariant; 
begin
URL := 'http://192.168.100.130';
Headers := 'Authorization: NTLM ' +
Base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)+ sLineBreak;
WebBrowser1.Navigate2(Url, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, Headers);
```

with Basic-Auth the same (not working) result.

Answer (score 0):

In our Intranet and with the Indy TIdHTTP component I used this for the username:

```
Username := "domainname\username";
```

It also worked in FireFox where the NTLM secured server will not cause a 'Domain' input field in the login dialog like in IE, but only the default user / password input fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned this call failed, why not check on SharePoint/IIS side what error was recorded? If it was a 401.1 error, Security event log should contain a Logon Failure record and tell you the reason. (Logon audit for failure must be enabled on the server via Local Security Policy.)